how can we override abstract class method in acumatica
I have try to override ShowSplits mehod of LineSplittingExtension  abstract class but debugger not coming on my method ShowSplits  which I have overirde
public class EWQCLineSplittingExtension:LineSplittingExtension {
    public static bool IsActive() {
        return EWQCFeatureSetHelper.IsEWQCManufacturingECCFeatureActive();
    }

    //override ShowSplits to update lot on line detail click
    public override IEnumerable ShowSplits(PXAdapter adapter) {

        lsselect.View.AskExt(true);
        //base.showSplits();
        MoveEntry moveEntryGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<MoveEntry>();
        EWQCAMMoveEntryExt moveEntryGraphExt = moveEntryGraph.GetExtension<EWQCAMMoveEntryExt>();
        moveEntryGraphExt.InsertLotsInLineDetails(false);

        return adapter.Get();
    }

}


Your class is not used by Acumatica, try to declare it in the similar way as POReceiptLineSplittingExtension
public class POReceiptLineSplittingExtension : LineSplittingExtension<POReceiptEntry, POReceipt, POReceiptLine, POReceiptLineSplit>

Another solution could be to create an extension of the LineSplittingExtension implementation used by your screen and override the ShowSplits method using [PXOverride].
using System;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.PO.GraphExtensions.POReceiptEntryExt;

namespace EWQC;

public class EWQCPOReceiptLineSplittingExtension : PXGraphExtension<POReceiptLineSplittingExtension, POReceiptEntry>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual IEnumerable ShowSplits(PXAdapter adapter, Func<PXAdapter, IEnumerable> baseMethod)
    {
        Base1.lsselect.View.AskExt(true);
        //base.showSplits();
        MoveEntry moveEntryGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<MoveEntry>();
        EWQCAMMoveEntryExt moveEntryGraphExt = moveEntryGraph.GetExtension<EWQCAMMoveEntryExt>();
        moveEntryGraphExt.InsertLotsInLineDetails(false);

        return adapter.Get();        
    }
}

